# Applying a function to an std::map values with for each and lambda fucntion

Tags: c++, stl

I want to do this :

```
std::map<std::string, bool> mapTrafficLights;

mapTrafficLights.emplace("RED", true);
mapTrafficLights.emplace("GREEN", true);
mapTrafficLights.emplace("ORANGE", true);

std::for_each(mapTrafficLights.begin(), mapTrafficLights.end(), []
(std::pair<std::string, bool>& it) {it.second = false; });

std::for_each(mapTrafficLights.begin(), mapTrafficLights.end(), [](std::pair<std::string, bool> it) {std::cout << it.first << " " << ((it.second) ? "ON" : "OFF") << std::endl; });
```

the line before the last won't compile if I keep the reference symbol "&" but when I remove it, it compiles but it didn't updates my map's values. I want to set all the booleans values to false but with this style of code in one line using STL tools.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type of the map's elements is `std::pair<const std::string, bool>`. This means that your lambda signature would require a type conversion to `std::pair<std::string, bool>`, requiring the creation of a temporary object. And you can't bind a non-const lvalue reference to a temporary. You need

```
std::for_each(mapTrafficLights.begin(), mapTrafficLights.end(),
             [] (std::pair<const std::string, bool>& it) {it.second = false; });
                           ^^^^^
```

Alternatively, use the map's `value_type`.

```
typedef std::map<std::string, bool> str_bool_map;
std::for_each(mapTrafficLights.begin(), mapTrafficLights.end(),
             [] (str_bool_map::value_type& it) {it.second = false; });
```

Note that for mutating ranges, it is more idiomatic to use `std::transform`. However, a range based loop might be the simplest solution:

```
for (auto& p : mapTrafficLights) p.second = false;
```

Answer (score 4):

`value_type` of `std::map<std::string, bool>` is `std::pair<const std::string, bool>>`. You are missing `const` in your code.

As you are clearly using C++11, why not use range-for loop and automatic type deduction?

```
for(auto& e: mapTrafficLights) {
    e.second = false;
}
```